# Thunderbird sent mail notification sound?

Tags: audio, thunderbird

Is is possible to add a sent mail notification sound in Thunderbird 3.1? I am running it on Mac OS X 10.6.4.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 2):

No no no!
He wants a sound strictly when he sends a message only, not syncs every last little thing in his inbox!
Try this route instead…
1. Search for (and install) the ThunderBird add-on named Tonequilla first.
2. After restarting (just to be sure), go to Tools > Message Filters…
3. Tap on the New button.
4. Make sure that Checking Mail After Classification Or Manually Run is chosen in the Apply Filter When: drop down list.
5. Choose to Match Any Of The Following in the option group.
(Seems to work best this way for me).
(Although, if you're adventurous, you could try All Of The Following instead).
6. At this point, choose From > Is > insert your email here.
7. In the Perform These Actions area, choose Play Sound and choose a sound you want.
Take a moment to preview the sound just to be sure it's what you want; TB has no known way of previewing sounds unless you're editing an associated filter.
8. Tap OK, close the Message Filters window and give it a dry run.
BTW, hope this works for you…
Side note: Did I mention I'm totally blind? Since birth?

Comment: I got this to work,but I had to change step 4 to just ticiking "After sending". I also had to set "Perform these actions" to "Play Sound" and choose a working audio file. Thank you! I'm *not* blind and couldn't figure this out myself!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's in "Preferences>General>When new message arrives" section:
Select either System Sound or add your own selecting the "Use following sound file" and browse to an mp3 (or other file) of your choice.

Hope it helps.

Note: When setting up the notification alert in Thunderbird there will be a glitch if you use IMAP. The glitch consist in the fact that the user gets notified also on sync. That means that while you write a reply you will hear the notification each time Thunderbird will sync the file with your IMAP server to save a current draft of the email you are putting together at that moment. It also happens when you sent an email... after sending it your Sent mailbox will be synchronized receiving the update to include a copy of the mail you just sent... that will also trigger an audio alert... it'a little annoying but not a major problem. To make sure if an alert you just heard is a false positive or not, just look at in the dock and if there is no visual (red dot with number of new messages) on the icon, then you can disregard the alert as it was a false positive and can continue do whatever you were doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is close to what I am looking for. In fact, I am hoping that Thunderbird will play a sound when I **send** mail, not just when I *receive* mail. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is now more than a decade old. But, I was searching for this very thing and this question kept popping up. So, I figured I'd add a 2023 answer. The original suggestion of Tonequila is now deprecated and seems to have been folded into Filtaquilla.

### To play a sound in Thunderbird after an email has been *sent*:

For Thunderbird 102...

Download and install the **[Filtaquila](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/)** extension add-on.

In the **Add-ons Manager**/Fitaquila options, make certain the "Play Sound" option is checked, and click <kbd>OK</kbd> (You can tick other options if you want those as well).

[image]

Then under `Tools > Message Filters` create a **new filter** for an account.

- Check the **After Sending** option
- Set the "Match" area to something relatively universal that all emails will have. All my emails have a subject, so I simply set the filter to act when there's anything in the Subject field.
- For actions, "Play Sound" should now be an option in the drop down menu. Choose it.
- Click the little folder icon to the right. Initially the folder will open at the location of the Filtaquila installation extras where there are a few sound you can use. If you want a custom sound simply navigate to where your sound file is and select it.
- Done.

[image]

I've found the .oog format for sounds works very well, but .wav seems to also work (I haven't tested other sound formats).